# Taxes on Family leave pay

Tags: labor-economics, taxation

I don't know if this is the correct forum for this question, but do we have to pay taxes on checks from the government that were paid from taxes in the first place.

For example, like Social security checks and Paid Family Leave checks?
If that is the case, what is the point of paying those taxes anyway?

If we pay `x%` on taxes on a `$y` paycheck every year, and after `n` number of years, we need to avail some of that money due to disability or paid family leave, etc, if we are to pay `z%` tax on that, would that be double taxation? even though `z` would be lesser than `x`?

Comment: This question may be more suitable for [Personal Finance & Money Stack Exchange](https://money.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you @KennyLJ. I have reposted this question there:
https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/123565/taxes-on-family-leave-pay